# Bootstrap padding not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I've correctly imported my bootstrap file, and it seems to be working because the rows and cols seem to be working.

However, I've got this file that uses a form:

```
.container
    .row
        .col-x-12.col-md-6
            form.form-horizontal(action="/location", method="get", role="form")

                .form-group
                    label.col-xs-10.col-sm-2.control-label(for="name") name
                    .col.xs-12.col-sm-10
                        input#name.form-control(name="name")

                .form-group
                    label.col-xs-10.col-sm-2.control-label(for="rating") rating
                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-10
                        select#rating.form-control.input-sm(name="rating")
                            option 1
                            option 2
                            option 3
                            option 4
                            option 5

                .form-group
                    label.col-xs-12.col-sm-2.control-label(for="review") review
                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-10
                        textarea#review.form-control(name="review", rows="5")

                button.btn.btn-default.pull-right Add my review
```

The padding for this doesn't seem to be working. The different form groups are not spaced apart. Also, the "Add review" button doesn't pull to the right.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `.col-x-12.col-md-6` is missing an "s". This should be `.col-xs-12.col-md-6` for starters. You can use `col-xs-offset-1` for example to give the form element spacing.

Comment: Apart from that, shouldn't bootstrap automatically be adding padding?

Answer (score 0):

First check the HTML structure is correct or not. If you are using custom style CSS, remove it and check the issue still exist. Finally share the entire HTML to look further.

Answer (score 0):

add .row class with .form-group class.

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the padding issue. However, the button still isn't being pulled to the right...

Comment: .form-group.row

Comment: .form-group.row text-right
 button.btn.btn-default Add my review

May be this can help you out

Comment: That doesn't change anything :(

Comment: can you please show me your page as text-right is working as i have tried above code.